# How to run define Tensorflow graph were all variables are in float16 instead instead of float32

Tags: python, tensorflow

By default, the variables Tensorflow is in float32. To save memory, I'm trying to run in float16. In my graph, every place where I could define the datatype as float16, I did. However, I get an error when I run the code

Here's my code below.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

vocabulary_size = 10
batch_size = 64 
embedding_size = 100 
num_inputs =4
num_sampled = 128 

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default(): #took out " , tf.device('/cpu:0')"


    train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, num_inputs ])
    train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])

    embeddings = tf.get_variable( 'embeddings', dtype=tf.float16,
        initializer= tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0, dtype=tf.float16) )

    softmax_weights = tf.get_variable( 'softmax_weights', dtype=tf.float16,
        initializer= tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                             stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size), dtype=tf.float16 ) )

    softmax_biases = tf.get_variable('softmax_biases', dtype=tf.float16,
        initializer= tf.zeros([vocabulary_size], dtype=tf.float16),  trainable=False )

    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #train data set is

    embed_reshaped = tf.reshape( embed, [batch_size*num_inputs, embedding_size] )

    segments= np.arange(batch_size).repeat(num_inputs)

    averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean(embed_reshaped, segments, name=None)

    sam_sof_los = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
                                   labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean( sam_sof_los )

    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss) 

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

And this is this is the error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    509                 as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 510                 preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
    511           except TypeError as err:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
   1143     if ret is None:
-> 1144       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1145 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _TensorTensorConversionFunction(t, dtype, name, as_ref)
    980         "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r" %
--> 981         (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
    982   return t

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float16 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("sampled_softmax_loss/Log:0", shape=(64, 1), dtype=float32)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-12d508b9e5d7> in <module>()
     46 
     47     sam_sof_los = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
---> 48                                    labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size)
     49 
     50     loss = tf.reduce_mean( sam_sof_los )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py in sampled_softmax_loss(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true, sampled_values, remove_accidental_hits, partition_strategy, name, seed)
   1347       partition_strategy=partition_strategy,
   1348       name=name,
-> 1349       seed=seed)
   1350   labels = array_ops.stop_gradient(labels, name="labels_stop_gradient")
   1351   sampled_losses = nn_ops.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py in _compute_sampled_logits(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true, sampled_values, subtract_log_q, remove_accidental_hits, partition_strategy, name, seed)
   1126     if subtract_log_q:
   1127       # Subtract log of Q(l), prior probability that l appears in sampled.
-> 1128       true_logits -= math_ops.log(true_expected_count)
   1129       sampled_logits -= math_ops.log(sampled_expected_count)
   1130 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    860     with ops.name_scope(None, op_name, [x, y]) as name:
    861       if isinstance(x, ops.Tensor) and isinstance(y, ops.Tensor):
--> 862         return func(x, y, name=name)
    863       elif not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
    864         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in sub(x, y, name)
   8316   if _ctx is None or not _ctx._eager_context.is_eager:
   8317     _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
-> 8318         "Sub", x=x, y=y, name=name)
   8319     _result = _op.outputs[:]
   8320     _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    544                   "%s type %s of argument '%s'." %
    545                   (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(attrs[input_arg.type_attr]).name,
--> 546                    inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
    547 
    548           types = [values.dtype]

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Sub' Op has type float32 that does not match type float16 of argument 'x'.
```

The error comes from line `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss`.

At first I thought perhaps tf.segment_mean may cast the output as a float32, so I tried casting averaged_embeds to float16 but I still get the same error.

From the documentation, there doesn't seem to be a way to define any data types in sampled_softmax_loss

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can only do it using a hack.

The issue comes from the call to:

```
  if sampled_values is None:
      sampled_values = candidate_sampling_ops.log_uniform_candidate_sampler(
          true_classes=labels,
          num_true=num_true,
          num_sampled=num_sampled,
          unique=True,
          range_max=num_classes,
          seed=seed)
```

which outputs an object of this type:

```
LogUniformCandidateSampler(
    sampled_candidates=<tf.Tensor 'LogUniformCandidateSampler:0' shape=(128,) dtype=int64>,
    true_expected_count=<tf.Tensor 'LogUniformCandidateSampler:1' shape=(64, 1) dtype=float32>,
    sampled_expected_count=<tf.Tensor 'LogUniformCandidateSampler:2' shape=(128,) dtype=float32>
)
```

The hack would be to generate yourself the `LogUniformCandidateSampler`, to cast its result as `tf.float16` and pass it to `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss`.

```
# Redefine it as the tensorflow one is not exposed.
LogUniformCandidateSampler = namedtuple("namedtuple", ["sampled_candidates", "true_expected_count", "sampled_expected_count"]) 
sampled_values = tf.nn.log_uniform_candidate_sampler(
      true_classes=tf.cast(train_labels, tf.int64), num_sampled=num_sampled,
      num_true=1,
      unique=True,
      range_max=vocabulary_size,
      seed=None)

sampled_value_16 = LogUniformCandidateSampler(
    sampled_values.sampled_candidates,
    tf.cast(sampled_values.true_expected_count, tf.float16),
    tf.cast(sampled_values.sampled_expected_count, tf.float16))

sam_sof_los = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
    weights=softmax_weights,
    biases=softmax_biases,
    inputs=averaged_embeds,
    labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size, 
    sampled_values=sampled_value_16)
```

But this is really a hack and it might have unexpected consequences (an expected one would be that the `tf.cast` operation is not differentiable).

Comment: The `sampled_values` are supposed to be randomly selected softmax weights/biases right? Could we just define a function which takes random softmax weights/biases at random, then use that as input to the `sampled_values `?

Comment: I'm thinking, if this really is a hack? Tf is not optimizing any parameters for the candidate sampler, perhaps it's not taking any differentiation with respect to the candidate sampler. The first tensor which is returned are randomly selected numbers, and that sort of function is not differential anyway. The other two tensors are basically number of negative samples/total number of classes (at least for uniformly distributed classes). There are variations; each time I run the candidate sample the values are a bit different. Il try hack but cast as float32 and see.

Comment: You're right, no differentiation is take wrt to he candidate sampler so you're fine on this side. I called it a hack because of the truncation from `float32` to `float16` numbers when truncating the `LogUniformCandidateSampler`. I'm just not sure about the effect of this truncation.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for float16, as I am getting 'nan' for the loss. But if I use your code, but just have everything at float32, the code works just fine. So it looks like using `cast` isn't the issue. There's something else interfering with tensorflow running at float16

Comment: Actually it does work. Every once in a while, something strange happens, because the loss returns 'nan', but overall it works and optimization is occurring. The only issue is that during debugging in eager execution, sampled_softmax_loss needs to have train_labels  to be casted again as int64, so `labels=tf.cast(train_labels, tf.int64)`. Not sure why this is, works in regular mode the way it was before.

Comment: Your solution ultimately works, but the issue is that it's very slow for some reason. Several orders of magnitude slower, at least 100x slower. I'm not sure what's causing this, it's hard to imagine casting the sampled values true_expected_count/sampled_expected_count from float32 to float16 is the cause.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. That's indeed surprising!

Comment: I opened a feature request for this on the official tensorflow github if you want to follow along https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23086