# Does tf.contrib.nn.sampled_sparse_softmax_loss allow for float16 training?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Currently, tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss does not allow for using float16.

[How to run define Tensorflow graph were all variables are in float16 instead instead of float32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711895/how-to-run-define-tensorflow-graph-were-all-variables-are-in-float16-instead-ins)

I'm looking at

tf.contrib.nn.sampled_sparse_softmax_loss

from

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/nn/sampled_sparse_softmax_loss

And it seems that this may allow float16 values. This code for this function is here

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.11/tensorflow/contrib/nn/python/ops/sampling_ops.py

Which seems to use tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Which seems to have support for float16

> logits: Unscaled log probabilities of shape [d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}, num_classes] and dtype float16, float32, or float64.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

However, when I try to use it, I get an error

My code

```
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

vocabulary_size = 10
batch_size = 64 
embedding_size = 100 
num_inputs =4
num_sampled = 128 

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default(): #took out " , tf.device('/cpu:0')"


    train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, num_inputs ])
    train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])

    embeddings = tf.get_variable( 'embeddings', dtype=tf.float16,
        initializer= tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0, dtype=tf.float16) )

    softmax_weights = tf.get_variable( 'softmax_weights', dtype=tf.float16,
        initializer= tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                             stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size), dtype=tf.float16 ) )

    softmax_biases = tf.get_variable('softmax_biases', dtype=tf.float16,
        initializer= tf.zeros([vocabulary_size], dtype=tf.float16),  trainable=False )

    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #train data set is

    embed_reshaped = tf.reshape( embed, [batch_size*num_inputs, embedding_size] )

    segments= np.arange(batch_size).repeat(num_inputs)

    averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean(embed_reshaped, segments, name=None)

    sam_sof_los = tf.contrib.nn.sampled_sparse_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
                                   labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean( sam_sof_los )

    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss) 

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

My error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    509                 as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 510                 preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
    511           except TypeError as err:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
   1143     if ret is None:
-> 1144       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1145 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _TensorTensorConversionFunction(t, dtype, name, as_ref)
    980         "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r" %
--> 981         (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
    982   return t

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float16 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("sampled_sparse_softmax_loss/Log:0", shape=(64, 1), dtype=float32)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-b68afd94e9bd> in <module>()
     41 
     42     sam_sof_los = tf.contrib.nn.sampled_sparse_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights , biases=softmax_biases , inputs=averaged_embeds,
---> 43                                    labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size)
     44 
     45 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/nn/python/ops/sampling_ops.py in sampled_sparse_softmax_loss(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, sampled_values, remove_accidental_hits, partition_strategy, name)
    331       remove_accidental_hits=remove_accidental_hits,
    332       partition_strategy=partition_strategy,
--> 333       name=name)
    334 
    335   # There is only one true label. _compute_sampled_logits puts the true logit

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py in _compute_sampled_logits(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true, sampled_values, subtract_log_q, remove_accidental_hits, partition_strategy, name, seed)
   1126     if subtract_log_q:
   1127       # Subtract log of Q(l), prior probability that l appears in sampled.
-> 1128       true_logits -= math_ops.log(true_expected_count)
   1129       sampled_logits -= math_ops.log(sampled_expected_count)
   1130 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    860     with ops.name_scope(None, op_name, [x, y]) as name:
    861       if isinstance(x, ops.Tensor) and isinstance(y, ops.Tensor):
--> 862         return func(x, y, name=name)
    863       elif not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
    864         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in sub(x, y, name)
   8316   if _ctx is None or not _ctx._eager_context.is_eager:
   8317     _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
-> 8318         "Sub", x=x, y=y, name=name)
   8319     _result = _op.outputs[:]
   8320     _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    544                   "%s type %s of argument '%s'." %
    545                   (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(attrs[input_arg.type_attr]).name,
--> 546                    inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
    547 
    548           types = [values.dtype]

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Sub' Op has type float32 that does not match type float16 of argument 'x'.
```